# secured spring boot backend with React Frontend

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, authorization, keycloak

i managed to secure my spring boot backend (localhost:8081) with keycloak as an authorization server (with an access token needed), but i want my frontend (react with port localhost:3000) to access the data which is secured. Thus meaning that localhost:3000/products should fetch data from localhost:8081/products after a successful login.

Could anyone guide me on this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You choose an OIDC client lib for react. It should handle

- redirection to authorization server for login
- redirection back from authorization server with authorization code
- exchange of authorization code for access, refresh and ID tokens
- automatic access token refreshing
- (maybe) automatically insert authorization header with bearer access token for configured routes

The requests your React app will issue to Spring resource server will then have required JWT access token.

#### PS

Make sure your Spring back-end [is configured as resource-server](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-oauth2-resource-servers) (and not as client).

Also make sure that you do **not** use the [deprecated Keycloak adapters for spring](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187).

Comment: could you suggest a library that is also documented well for beginners? I managed to configure my backend as a resource server and i am also fetching my data in my react app, i also imported this https://github.com/bjerkio/oidc-react library, but i dont really know where to start. I have got the feeling that there are no beginner friendly sources for OIDC

Comment: No, I can't. You have to master OAuth2 vocabulary and flows (at minimum authorization-code and client credentials) before you can configure its actors (authorization-server, resource-server and client). Once you have this background, you'll also have to read the manuals for each actors. The link in my answer points to quick-start Keycloak and resource-server, but you have to refer to the READMEs me of the lib you chose to achieve what I list in your React app (login, tokens acquisition, authorizing requests).

Comment: Hi ch4mp, i managed to do the tasks you listed, so i set up my backend as a resource server, my frontend redirects to keycloak for authentification, after a successfull login, the frontend sends a request with the bearer token in the header, everthing works fine. But im still confused, why do i need a JWT decoder in my backend? Why do i need token validation in my backend, it also works without any decoder or validation

Comment: This JWT holds user identity signed by Keycloak. Validation on resource-server checks that this token is authentic (unchanged and issued by the right Keycloak instance). This JWT is used to build the Authentication instance in Spring security-context to take access decisions (with `@PreAuthorize` expressions for instance, see tutorials and samples linked in the answer)

Comment: Hi ch4mp, when using spring boot starter oauth2 resource server dependency, the default JwtDecoder bean looks like this: @Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    return JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(issuerUri);
}, why would anybody overwrite this bean?

Comment: I don't overwrite this specific bean. I once did to support multiple issuers, but was pointed in another direction by spring-security team (override authentication manager instead). Note that if you don't use one of "my" starters, you'll have to override other beans as done in the first of the tutorials linked in the answer (to map Keycloak roles to Spring authorities as a minimum).